# Grok RSpec test failing

Tags: ruby, rspec, logstash, logstash-grok

I'm trying to get grok working with logstash but struggling to get off the starting block. I've tried to simplify things down to a succinct test which is here:

```
require "test_utils"

describe "basic grokking" do
  extend LogStash::RSpec

  config <<-CONFIG
    filter {
      grok {
        match => [ "message", "%{IP:client} %{WORD:method} %{URIPATHPARAM:request} %{NUMBER:bytes} %{NUMBER:duration}" ]
      }
    }
  CONFIG

  sample ({'@message' => '55.3.244.1 GET /index.html 15824 0.043'}) do

    puts subject.inspect # view http://www.codeshare.io/OhDC0

    insist { subject["client"] } == "55.3.244.1"
  end
end
```

I get the following error:

```
  1) basic grokking "{"@message":"55.3.244.1 GET /index.html 15824 0.043..." when processed
 Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
 Insist::Failure:
   Expected "55.3.244.1", but got nil
```

No amount of syntax tweaking is getting a result and I also can't figure out how to inspect the `subject` to find out what is there.

**The ultimate aim** is to use grok to extract the following `HttpRequestId`:

```
[HttpRequestId = e29041b2-a4a0-4bf3-ba05-2de5e7bcf444] 2015/04/10 08:12:51:632 [DEBUG] ... log message ...
```

Using something like this:

```
grok {
    match => [ "Message", "\[HttpRequestId = %{UUID:HttpRequestId}" ]
}
```

**NOTE** I have checked my patterns against https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ and they work. It's something to do with the way I am testing.

Comment: What language are you writing the wrapper for this in? Looks like Ruby; might be worth tagging.

Comment: Yes it's ruby. Added the tag. Reference: http://koendc.github.io/2013/10/11/logstash-test-configuration.html

Comment: What version of logstash are you using?  I'm encountering the same issue with logstash 1.4.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After extensive investigation, here's the minimal rspec test for a grok expression for logstash 1.4.2:

```
# encoding: utf-8

require "test_utils"

describe "simple test" do
  extend LogStash::RSpec

   config <<-CONFIG
    filter {
      grok {
         match        => { "message" => "am%{GREEDYDATA:foo}" }
      }
    }
  CONFIG

  sample 'amessage' do
    insist { subject["foo"] } == "essage"
    insist { subject["message"] } == "amessage"
  end
end
```

Note that you must have the `# encoding ...` line, otherwise you'll get the `Expected "essage", but got nil` message.

This mailing list message helped: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/logstash-users/rs6jlAxv36M/1ylU-GJ-DVQJ

Comment: Now I see the #encoding everywhere. I'm sure I've never seen it before now! Look forward to trying this out tomorrow.

Comment: I will do. Didn't have a chance today. I'll keep this up to date when I have something.

Comment: Apologies for the delay, this work is on the back-burner now so I'm only looking at it when I get the chance. Thanks for pointing out the encoding, that was the trick.